# Is Google Chromecast mirroring done through WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, chromecast

Read from here:
http://giovanni.bajo.it/post/60352255570/airplay-vs-chromecast-breakdown-and-differences

it says:
in fact, the basic video support is just a simple html with a  tag, while mirroring is being done through WebRTC.

is this true?

Answer (score 3):

Tab mirroring is done via WebRTC protocols last time I checked.  Note that things like NetFlix, Youtube, etc are not webrtc/tab-mirroring; they tell the Chromecast to fetch things itself in the Chromecast app appropriate.

Firefox for Android (and soon desktop) supports WebRTC tab mirroring with Roku and soon others (Matchstick (based on FirefoxOS) and others).